# Output Encoding | XSS - JAVA

Tags: java, xss, esapi

I have mitigating XSS vulnerability using Input Validation and Output Encoding using ESAPI. Am getting the below value for the field after doing output encoding

```
"imp_type": "General&#x20;Value&#x20;and&#x20;Use&#x20;Value",
```

instead of

```
"imp_type": "General Value and Use Value",
```

The code is

```
public void setImp_type(String imp_type) {

      this.imposition_type = ESAPI.encoder().encodeForHTMLAttribute(imp_type);
  }
```

I guess the **&#x20** is related for space? Can anyone help how to handle this.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do.  I would expect all characters passed to an encoding method to be appropriately escaped.  This is working precisely as designed.  Maybe you're encoding before input validation?  Don't do that.  Encode only right when you display to the user, or hand off to another interpreter.

Comment: Yes, its working good. I had to disable the encoding before input validation

Comment: Don't encode before data validation.  Canonicalize to detect mixed/multiple encoding and validate both the canonicalized and original data.  Store the original data.  Encode only on output.

Comment: Don't turn encoding off.

Comment: Yes @avgvstvs , i have done canonicalization and done output encoding